# PHP FFMPEG How to calculate file size of video from bitrate and duration before conversion?

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I am using php-ffmpeg (a PHP api to ffmpeg) to probe video files before they are converted. I am getting all the information I need just fine, but I want to use it to calculate the estimated file size of the video once it has been converted so that I can convert videos more efficiently for quality vs space etc.

The post-conversion file size only has to be an estimate. So far I have tried multiplying the duration by the anticipated video bitrate plus the anticipated audio bitrate. However, that gives me a size way larger than the original video file that has a higher video and audio bitrate. I'm assuming there is a compression factor that may have to be taken into account for each different video codec, but am just trying to get somewhere with .mp4/m4v for now.

This is what I have tried;

```
// duration | vid bitrate | aud bitrate
$estimated_converted_size = $duration * ((4992 * 1024) + (128 * 1024));
```

The result for a video of 24 seconds, with a video bitrate of 29302kbps and file size of 87.86 MB estimates as being 121.11 MB once converted down to 4992kbs - clearly not right!

I'm not too clued up on the technicals of video, but is there a way of fairly accurately estimating the file size after conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`29302kbps` is kilobits per second

`87.86 MB` is megabytes.

There are 8 bits in a byte. `121.11Mb` equals `15.13MB` `(121.11/8)`

Comment: Ha ha. I think you could be on to something there. I'll check whether I have made such a silly mistake and if so I will come back, admit it and accept your answer and lay low for a while!

Comment: I'll get my coat.